# Find $P(B|L)$ and $P(L|B)$

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

A deck of cards has $3$ orange cards and $7$ blue cards. Two cards are selected a random without replacement. $B=$ both cards are blue, $L=$ at least one card is blue.
$n(S)= C(10,2)$

a) find $P(B|L)$

b) find $P(L|B)$

Attempt:

$P(B∣L)=\frac{P(L)}
{P(B∩L)}$

$P(B∩L)=P(B)$

​
Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Can you find $P(L)$? Do you know how to calculate $P(B \cap L)$?

Comment: Is $P(B∩L)= P(B)$ ?

Comment: Yes, if both cards are blue then at least one of them are blue.

Comment: Also, $\mathsf P(B\mid L) = \dfrac{\mathsf P(B\cap L)}{\mathsf P(L)}$

Comment: how do I get $P(B)$ and $P(L)$ ?

Comment: $10$ total cards, $7$ of which are blue and $3$ of which are orange. $P(B)$ represents the probability that, when selecting two cards at random, both these cards are blue. So, you have ${7 \choose 2}$ hypothesis of selecting $2$ of the $7$ blue cards... can you continue to determine $P(B)$ with this hint? ($P(L)$ should be analogous).

Comment: Is it $\frac{C(7,2)}{C(10,2)}$ ?

Comment: As indicated, you want $$\frac{p(B \cap L)}{p(L)},$$ where $$p(L) = \frac{\binom{10}{2} - \binom{3}{2}}{\binom{10}{2}}$$ and $$p(B \cap L) = p(B) = \frac{\binom{7}{2}}{\binom{10}{2}}.$$

Comment: The event that both cards are blue is a subset of the event that at least one card is blue.  Therefore, $~p(L|B) = 1.~$  That is, if you are given that both cards are blue, then you are **guaranteed** that at least one of the cards is blue.

Answer (score 0):

For the event B, the probability that the first card is blue is $\frac {7}{10}$ and the probability that the second card is blue is $\frac 69$ as card are selected without replacement.Therefore,

$$P(B)= \frac {7}{10}\cdot \frac69$$

For event L we notice that probability of at least one card being blue is same as one minus the probability that both cards are orange which can be calculated similarly using the same approach as for B.
$$P(L) = 1-\frac{3}{10}\cdot \frac29= \frac{84}{90}$$

Now I guess it's easy to see... By considering, as pointed out in comments that $P(B\bigcap L)=P(B)$ that

$$P(B|L)= \frac{P(B\bigcap L)}{P(L)}=\frac12$$

And also $P(L|B)$ is the probability of happening of L given that B has already occured. Since B has occured which means both cards are blue it is automatically true that atleast one is blue or L has occurred. Hence it is equal to 1 as it is a sure event.